# how to call lstat(2) instead of lstat(3)?

Tags: c, linux

How do I call the lstat system call in linux/c, not the lstat wrapper around it (lstat(3))? There is no SYS_lstat for syscall(SYS_lstat...

Comment: What's the difference?  (Honestly - my machine doesn't have `lstat(3)`.)

Comment: there is probably no difference, but I can only use system calls, not library calls.

Comment: hmmm.. actually neither does my machine.. good point. Problem solved.

Comment: @Carl: unless your machine is quite exotic, you do have `lstat(3)`, but it's just a wrapper around `lstat(2)`. Most man pages in section 2 are in fact documenting C library function, so should really be in section 3. The Linux lstat(2) man page documents lstat(3) but has a paragraph on the "underlying kernel interface".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the syscall directly, you need to make sure your definition of `struct stat` and the kernel's definition agree. Also if you're on a 32-bit machine you should probably never use the deprecated `lstat` syscall but instead the `lstat64` one, since the former will fail on large files. These and numerous other issues are why it's a **bad idea** to make syscalls yourself instead of using the standard library; the latter wraps around all the legacy compatibility cruft and gives you a standards-compliant POSIX interface.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you have incomplete headers, SYS_lstat is listed in /usr/include/bits/syscall.h on my Ubuntu 10.4 system.

```
#define SYS_lstat __NR_lstat
```

Then in asm/unistd_64.h:

```
#define __NR_lstat                              6
```

Or perhaps asm/unistd_32.h:

```
#define __NR_lstat              107
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have it on CentOS 5 as well.

Comment: it is in the headers on mine as well but the compiler still does not recognise it.